# Qt calling threads in a loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qfuture

I have a code like this with function `double myfunction(double)` that takes a lot of time to finish.

Using Qt (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html), how can I run the loop utilizing a thread for every `myfunction` call to have smaller computation time? Does this make sense?

```
std::vector<double> parameters;        //vector full of input values
std::vector<double> results;           //vector to store results in

for(uint i=0; i<parameters.size(); i++)
{
   double parameter = parameters.at(i);
   double result = myfunction(parameter);
   results.push_back(result);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use C++11 threads instead? BTW, threads doesn't always mean faster.

Comment: C++ threads - I dont know it exists :-D. I thought running the function in parralel (ie. in threads) will be faster then one after each other. If my understanding is correct.

Comment: Isn't `results` empty at the start and you fill it as the `result` is computed? In this case, the loop won't execute i.e. `i < results.size()`. And, `results.at(i)` will throw an exception `std::out_of_range` if it is used when the vector is empty. Correction: `i < parameters.size()` and `results.push_back(result);`.

Comment: Azeem - thank you - corrected.

Comment: @vlad: You're welcome! Better to use C++11's [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) if you're iterating the whole vector. You can divide your workload and pass that to multiple threads to process and then aggregate the result. Take a look at C++11's [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread). But, you have to benchmark your single- and multi-threaded solutions for performance to figure out which one works better.

Comment: Have you tried using `QtConcurrent::run`?  If so what problems did you encounter?

Comment: G.M. - No I haven't. I am not sure how, that is why I tried to ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example usage of `QtConcurrent::run` for you own case would be something like (untested)...

```
std::vector<double> parameters;     // vector full of input values.
std::vector<double> results;        // Empty vector to store results.

/*
 * Each call to QtConcurrent::run returns a QFuture.  Store
 * these so we can wait on the results.
 */
std::vector<QFuture<double>> futures;

/*
 * Start all tasks and store the QFutures.
 */
for (auto parameter: parameters) {
    futures.push_back(QtConcurrent::run(&myfunction, parameter));
}

/*
 * Wait for each QFuture in turn and save its result.
 */
for (auto &f: futures) {
    results.push_back(f.result());
}
```

Comment: G.M.'s solution works marvelously. If the number of parameters is less-than-or-equal-to the number of processor cores, the time to complete all is the duration of the longest execution of myFunction() because they all run in parallel. However, the second for-loop where the results are accumulated blocks until all results are computed. If called on the UI thread, the UI will freeze until the last result is computed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `QtConcurrent::mapped()` and a `QFutureWatcher` so that all processing occurs asynchronously.

`QFutureWatcher` emits a `finished()` signal when all processing is complete. Results are accumulated by a single `QFuture` which is managed by the `QFutureWatcher`. Most importantly, the UI never freezes.

*my_project.pro*:

```
# must include "concurrent" to use QtConcurrent::mapped()
QT += concurrent
...
```

*MappedProcessor.h*:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QFutureWatcher>
#include <vector>

class MappedProcessor : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MappedProcessor(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    void processValues();

private slots:
    void handleProcessingFinished();

private:
    static double myFunction(double value);

    QFutureWatcher<double> m_futureWatcher;
};
```

*MappedProcessor.cpp*:

```
#include "MappedProcessor.h"
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent>
#include <QList>
#include <QThread>

MappedProcessor::MappedProcessor(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    connect(&m_futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<double>::finished,
            this, &MappedProcessor::handleProcessingFinished);
}

void MappedProcessor::processValues()
{
    // create some values to process
    std::vector<double> parameters;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
        parameters.push_back(i);

    auto sequence = QVector<double>::fromStdVector(parameters);
    auto future = QtConcurrent::mapped(sequence, myFunction);
    m_futureWatcher.setFuture(future);
}

void MappedProcessor::handleProcessingFinished()
{
    // convert the results to std::vector<double>
    auto theResults = m_futureWatcher.future().results().toVector().toStdVector();

    qDebug() << "Received" << theResults.size() << "results";
}

// pretend to be a long running calculation...
double MappedProcessor::myFunction(double value)
{
    QThread::msleep(10000);
    return value;
}
```